# My code doesn't display anything in the p element after I call the "vysledek" function and the if statement is correct

Tags: javascript, html

I watched a Youtube tutorial on how to make new selection elements based on the first selection, this part works. However when I try to work with values of new selections, it seems that there are not any values that I can work with.

Does someone have a solution? It seems like my select elements have no values.

```js
function populate(s1, s2, ) {
  /*let tri = "3";
  let dva = "2";
  let naDruhou = dva.sup();
  let naTreti = tri.sup();
  */
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "l") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mm|mm", "cm|cm", "dm|dm", "m|m", "km|km"];
  } else if (s1.value == "m") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mg|mg", "g|g", "dkg|dkg", "kg|kg"];
  } else if (s1.value == "t") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "s|s", "min|min", "h|h"];
  } else if (s1.value == "I") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mA|mA", "A|A"];
  } else if (s1.value == "T") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "°C|°C", "°F|°F", "K|K"];
  } else if (s1.value == "V") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "ml|ml", "cl|cl", "dl|dl", "l|l",
      "hl|hl", "mm^3|mm^3", "cm^3|cm^3", "dm^3|dm^3", "m^3|m^3", "km^3|km^3"
    ];
  } else if (s1.value == "U") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mV|mV", "V|V", "kV|kV", "MV|MV"];
  } else if (s1.value == "R") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mΩ|mΩ", "Ω|Ω", "kΩ|kΩ", "MΩ|MΩ"];
  } else if (s1.value == "S") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mm^2|mm^2", "cm^2|cm^2", "dm^2|dm^2",
      "m^2|m^2", "km^2|km^2", "a|a", "ha|ha"
    ];
  }
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    let pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    let newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}

function zmena(a, b) {
  var a = document.getElementById("velicina");
  var b = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka");
  b.innerHTML = "";
  if (a.value == "l") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mm|mm", "cm|cm", "dm|dm", "m|m", "km|km"];
  } else if (a.value == "m") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mg|mg", "g|g", "dkg|dkg", "kg|kg"];
  } else if (a.value == "t") {
    var vybery = ["|", "s|s", "min|min", "h|h"];
  } else if (a.value == "I") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mA|mA", "A|A"];
  } else if (a.value == "T") {
    var vybery = ["|", "°C|°C", "°F|°F", "K|K"];
  } else if (a.value == "V") {
    var vybery = ["|", "ml|ml", "cl|cl", "dl|dl", "l|l",
      "hl|hl", "mm^3|mm^3", "cm^3|cm^3", "dm^3|dm^3", "m^3|m^3"
    ];
  } else if (a.value == "U") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mV|mV", "V|V", "kV|kV", "MV|MV"];
  } else if (a.value == "R") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mΩ|mΩ", "Ω|Ω", "kΩ|kΩ", "MΩ|MΩ"];
  } else if (a.value == "S") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mm^2|mm^2", "cm^2|cm^2", "dm^2|dm^2",
      "m^2|m^2", "km^2|km^2", "a|a", "ha|ha"
    ];
  }
  for (var vyber in vybery) {
    let par = vybery[vyber].split("|");
    let novyVyber = document.createElement("option");
    novyVyber.value = par[0];
    novyVyber.innerHTML = par[1];
    b.options.add(novyVyber);
    //console.log = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka").value;
  }
}

function vysledek() {
  let vstup = document.getElementById("vstup").value;
  let vstupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vstupniJednotka").value;
  let vystupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka").value;
  let velicina = document.getElementById("velicina").value;
  const l = {
    mm: 1,
    cm: 10,
    dm: 100,
    m: 1000,
    km: 1000000
  };
  if (velicina == "l") {
    let vystup = vstup * l[vstupniJednotka] * l[vystupniJednotka];
  }
  document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML = "Výsledek: " + vystup + vystupniJednotka;
}
```

```css
label,
select,
input {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Převodník jednotek</h1>
<p>Tato aplikace umí převádět různé jednotky</p><br>
<label for="velicina">Vyberte veličinu:</label>
<select name="velicina" id="velicina" onchange="populate(this.id,'vstupniJednotka'); zmena(this.id, 'vystupniJednotka');">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="l">Délka</option>
  <option value="m">Hmotnost</option>
  <option value="t">Čas</option>
  <option value="I">Elektrický proud</option>
  <option value="T">Termodynamická teplota</option>
  <option value="V">Objem</option>
  <option value="U">Elektrické napětí</option>
  <option value="R">Elektrický odpor</option>
  <option value="S">Obsah</option>
</select><br>
<label for="vstup">Zadejte hodnotu, kterou chcete převést:</label>
<input id="vstup" type="number">
<select name="vstupniJednotka" id="vstupniJednotka"></select><br>
<label for="vystupniJednotka">Zadejte jednotku výsledku:</label>
<select name="vystupniJednotka" id="vystupniJednotka" onchange="vysledek()"></select><br>
<p id="vysledek"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you define `vystup` using `let` *within* the `if` condition, so it's locally scoped. To fix this you can declare it outside the `if` condition and update its value within, something like this:

```
function vysledek() {
  let vstup = document.getElementById("vstup").value;
  let vstupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vstupniJednotka").value;
  let vystupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka").value;
  let velicina = document.getElementById("velicina").value;
  let vystup = '';

  const l = {
    mm: 1,
    cm: 10,
    dm: 100,
    m: 1000,
    km: 1000000
  };

  if (velicina == "l") {
    vystup = vstup * l[vstupniJednotka] * l[vystupniJednotka];
  }
  document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML = "Výsledek: " + vystup + vystupniJednotka;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
function populate(s1, s2, ) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "l") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mm|mm", "cm|cm", "dm|dm", "m|m", "km|km"];
  } else if (s1.value == "m") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mg|mg", "g|g", "dkg|dkg", "kg|kg"];
  } else if (s1.value == "t") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "s|s", "min|min", "h|h"];
  } else if (s1.value == "I") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mA|mA", "A|A"];
  } else if (s1.value == "T") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "°C|°C", "°F|°F", "K|K"];
  } else if (s1.value == "V") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "ml|ml", "cl|cl", "dl|dl", "l|l",
      "hl|hl", "mm^3|mm^3", "cm^3|cm^3", "dm^3|dm^3", "m^3|m^3", "km^3|km^3"
    ];
  } else if (s1.value == "U") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mV|mV", "V|V", "kV|kV", "MV|MV"];
  } else if (s1.value == "R") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mΩ|mΩ", "Ω|Ω", "kΩ|kΩ", "MΩ|MΩ"];
  } else if (s1.value == "S") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "mm^2|mm^2", "cm^2|cm^2", "dm^2|dm^2",
      "m^2|m^2", "km^2|km^2", "a|a", "ha|ha"
    ];
  }
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    let pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    let newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}

function zmena(a, b) {
  var a = document.getElementById("velicina");
  var b = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka");
  b.innerHTML = "";
  if (a.value == "l") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mm|mm", "cm|cm", "dm|dm", "m|m", "km|km"];
  } else if (a.value == "m") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mg|mg", "g|g", "dkg|dkg", "kg|kg"];
  } else if (a.value == "t") {
    var vybery = ["|", "s|s", "min|min", "h|h"];
  } else if (a.value == "I") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mA|mA", "A|A"];
  } else if (a.value == "T") {
    var vybery = ["|", "°C|°C", "°F|°F", "K|K"];
  } else if (a.value == "V") {
    var vybery = ["|", "ml|ml", "cl|cl", "dl|dl", "l|l",
      "hl|hl", "mm^3|mm^3", "cm^3|cm^3", "dm^3|dm^3", "m^3|m^3"
    ];
  } else if (a.value == "U") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mV|mV", "V|V", "kV|kV", "MV|MV"];
  } else if (a.value == "R") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mΩ|mΩ", "Ω|Ω", "kΩ|kΩ", "MΩ|MΩ"];
  } else if (a.value == "S") {
    var vybery = ["|", "mm^2|mm^2", "cm^2|cm^2", "dm^2|dm^2",
      "m^2|m^2", "km^2|km^2", "a|a", "ha|ha"
    ];
  }
  for (var vyber in vybery) {
    let par = vybery[vyber].split("|");
    let novyVyber = document.createElement("option");
    novyVyber.value = par[0];
    novyVyber.innerHTML = par[1];
    b.options.add(novyVyber);
    //console.log = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka").value;
  }
}

function vysledek() {
  let vstup = document.getElementById("vstup").value;
  let vstupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vstupniJednotka").value;
  let vystupniJednotka = document.getElementById("vystupniJednotka").value;
  let velicina = document.getElementById("velicina").value;
  let vystup = '';
  const l = {
    mm: 1,
    cm: 10,
    dm: 100,
    m: 1000,
    km: 1000000
  };
  if (velicina == "l") {
    vystup = vstup * l[vstupniJednotka] * l[vystupniJednotka];
  }
  document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML = "Výsledek: " + vystup + vystupniJednotka;
}
```

```css
label,
select,
input {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

````html
<h1>Převodník jednotek</h1>
<p>Tato aplikace umí převádět různé jednotky</p><br>
<label for="velicina">Vyberte veličinu:</label>
<select name="velicina" id="velicina" onchange="populate(this.id,'vstupniJednotka'); zmena(this.id, 'vystupniJednotka');">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="l">Délka</option>
  <option value="m">Hmotnost</option>
  <option value="t">Čas</option>
  <option value="I">Elektrický proud</option>
  <option value="T">Termodynamická teplota</option>
  <option value="V">Objem</option>
  <option value="U">Elektrické napětí</option>
  <option value="R">Elektrický odpor</option>
  <option value="S">Obsah</option>
</select><br>
<label for="vstup">Zadejte hodnotu, kterou chcete převést:</label>
<input id="vstup" type="number">
<select name="vstupniJednotka" id="vstupniJednotka"></select><br>
<label for="vystupniJednotka">Zadejte jednotku výsledku:</label>
<select name="vystupniJednotka" id="vystupniJednotka" onchange="vysledek()"></select><br>
<p id="vysledek"></p>
```
````

Comment: Why not `let vystup = 0;` ?